# How to create a Newsletter which is back end manageable in Typo3 v10

Tags: typo3, newsletter

I need to create a Newsletter Subscription form in my typo3 site. And I want to just store the data in Typo3 so that we can use it later for Mailchimp or another NL Tool.  Which is the most suitable extension for this? And I have tried [**newsletter_subscribe**](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/newsletter_subscribe/) extension, but I m totally confused about how to do this. Please help me if anyone knows this.

My design is here[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evEnb.png)

I got an error when I try to configure this extension[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSDP8.png)

Any help is appreciatable. Thanks!!

Comment: The solution highly depends on how you wan't to manage your subscribers. You can store them locally or send them trough an API to a mailchimp like service. Could you update your question with more details on that?

Comment: Sure. I want to  store them in Typo3 so that I can use it later for mailchimp or another NL Tool

Answer (score 0):

When I see your image design, just a warning :it's good to keep it simple, but keep it GDPR compliant too, and don't forget the consent checkbox.

You can handle the subcription form with the form framework extension or powermail extension, because it's just a form. Both can store datas in the backend. I remember that powermail propose a double optin' behaviour which can be usefull for that kind of form subscription.

Also, if you finally want to handle everything in TYPO3 (I mean the newsletter email sending), luxletter is a good newsletter extension that is TYPO3 V10 compatible.

Cheers,
Rachel

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will try :)